# Catching errors, the onerror event

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, throw

I am trying to catch errors that happens in the users web browser. I want the user to send a screenshot of the error, possibly including file, line numbers etc.

I hoped it would be rather simple and standardized now. But I wonder. With trial and error I came up with this:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    let error = e;
    if (e.error) error = e.error;
    let msg = "There was an error.";
    msg += " Please go to https://somewhere.com/";
    msg += " and post an image of this message. \n\nError: ";
    if (error.message) {
        msg += error.message;
    } else {
        msg += error;
    }
    if (error.stack) msg += "\n\n"+error.stack;
    console.log(msg);
    alert(msg);
});
```

Does it work? Hm, maybe, but not as I expected. Trying this from the console for example did not give me "test error" in the alert popup, but "Script error":

```
setTimeout(function(){throw "test error"}, 1000)
```

How should I do this? (I am only interested in newer browsers and actually just Chrome at the moment. Maybe Firefox and Edge later.)

### And, a rather important thing: Which errors do I catch by just adding this handler? Asynch? Promises? Etc.

EDIT: First summing up the answers so far. The most important thing is the difference between those two (only the second one gives a traceback in Chrome):

```
throw "some error"
throw Error("some error")
```

Now to the other half of the problem. Which errors are caught. I get this in the console, for example, but it never reaches my error handler above. Why? (This is from IndexedDB, using idb.js)

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Key already exists in the object store.
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-error

Comment: @SergeK. Thanks, it might be useful, but it does not help for the case I tested. If I look at ev.view and ev.detail (as expected since this is not UIEvent, of course). And the spec for Event does not give any details.

Comment: Eh, ev.view and ev.detail are undefined (I dropped that from the comment above somehow).

Answer (score 1):

You may need to throw an error :)

```
 throw new Error("test error")
```

Comment: It does not make any difference here. And I am not interested in that part. I am interested in how to catch the errors.

Comment: @leo [well, at least it provides a better error message](http://jsbin.com/hiyuyazuna/edit?console)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I think it is exactly the same error message.

Comment: Eh, you are right. It gives a better error message. It adds a traceback.

Comment: Wonder why Chrome only gives a traceback if Error(...) is used. Looks like a bug to me, but there might be some reason for the different behavior.

Comment: @leo cause of the error constructor being `new Error(message, row, column)`. If you dont pass row and column it will take the position the error is constructed...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error#Syntax

Comment: But if I just do "throw 'something'" then I do not give a line number. And the error object seems to be implicitly constructed...

Comment: @leo no, it does not get constructed implicitly

Comment: Jonas W, what is happening then? When you catch the error it looks like an Error object, at least to me.

Comment: @leo without `new Error` its an Error event which contains a string, with the constructor its an error event holding an error.

Comment: Jonas W, yes there is some difference. But I you want to explain more about the difference I would be glad. I still think an implicit Error object is constructed with just "throw 'something'" and see no reason why it should not contain the line number and stack.

Comment: @leo you think wrong. There is no implicit construction!

Comment: Jonas W, maybe. But what is it I see then in the "error" event listener? Can you maybe describe what happens in the two cases?

Comment: @leo may look at your own code?? `msg += " and post an image of this message. \n\nError: ";`

Comment: Jonas W. Do "throw 'something' and look in the console output. You will find an ErrorEvent there. (But I am curious why you are saying I am wrong. If you want I would be glad if you explained.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, that html file seems to work fine:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener('error', (e) => {
            console.log(e);
        });

        setTimeout(() => { throw 'Hello world'; }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

That should output the proper error to the console. However when I try to set up the handler in DevTools console directly and throw an error in timeout handler, I am getting 'Script error.'. It looks like Chrome thinks it is a same origin policy violation in the latter case.

Comment: Yes, confirmed that. And just as Jonas W pointed out you get some more info (a traceback) if you do "throw Error(...)".